# Reading the encoder cost value in a controller/service

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

Symfony 4 is a great product but I am having trouble understanding Dependency Injection and how to actually grab that data in my service.  So I will ask a simple question and see if an answer will help me.

in the security.yaml file I have defined an encode in the encoders section.  It looks like

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost:      15
```

QUESTION:  In my controller App\Controller\UserController, what do I need to inject to read the cost value?  It is not the encode, as is only has a private value of cost, which is NOT made public.

Thanks,

Craig

Comment: Take a look at var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php.  This is the "compiled" DI container which was generated by merging all the config files and then doing a bunch of additional compiler pass magic.   Search for bcrypt and you will find something like: BCryptPasswordEncoder', 'arguments' => array(0 => 15) This is basically saying how to instantiate the encoder passing a value of 15 (the cost) as the first argument in the constructor.  There is no explicit way to directly get the cost value from the container.  Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse your cost value you can create a parameter in your services.yaml:

```
parameters:
    encoder.cost: 15
```

and then use this parameter inside your security.yaml:

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost:      %encoder.cost%
```

In your controller you can then simply call `getParameter()` to reuse the value, if needed. Even better directly provide the parameter to the service you want to use it in.

If you look at [the sorce code for the BcryptPasswordEncoder](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/BCryptPasswordEncoder.php) - and probably this is true for options passed to the other encoders as well - the value is not exposed. That's because it should not matter to your application which cost the encoder uses, so it would be "wrong" to depend on it.

You could use reflection or `Closure::bind()` to expose the value, but I would not do this, especially not in production code. The only other means would be to create a custom encoder based on the original and expose it there, should you have a compelling use case for reusing that value.

Another important thing is, that the values you provide in configuration such as `security:`, `framework:` or `doctrine:` are usually encapsulated into the services and not available to you other then by binding them to a parameter as shown above and reusing them. They are usually not even set as parameters inside the container. This is for a good reason should the configuration change for whatever reason you don't want other parts of your application that now rely on them to break. It is therefore safer to use custom parameters or sometimes even duplicating the values to ensure an update/change does not have unwanted side effects. The same is true for using these values and even parameters in your controller. Most IDEs will not warn you about the value not being set and then your code might break or behave weirdly because the value is not what you expected.

Comment: Thanks for this dbrumann,   I had looked at this option, but looking into the future I think I see the demise of parameters on the horizon, as the getParameter is now marked as final.  I have found this using a my own getParameter method to overwrite the standard Symfony controller method.   Allows me to step over a missing parameter using a default value.

Comment: Sorry, will not mark as answer, as insufficient details on how to reveal the details, (examples are best)  and the fact that parameters may be no longer available in code in the future development of Symfony.

Comment: Feel free not to mark the answer, if you don't find it helpful. The answer does not contain any code samples, because it's simple to write and just copying them without thinking of their drawbacks will probably incur unwarranted technical debt. Parameters are not in demise. The method is set final to ensure people don't overwrite it in their code. If it were to be deprecated it will be marked as such.